# IPhone Video Streaming Problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I want to implement video streaming in my project. So, Is there any tutorial that works? Videos are stored at server side. So, to fetch video using url and play it on MPMoviePlayerViewController .
Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For video streaming in iPhone you can use ffmpeg concept.FFmpeg is a complete, cross-platform solution to record, convert and stream audio and video. It includes libavcodec - the leading audio/video codec library.Have a look at these sites for samples,

1. https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg
2. http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/

Comment: what is this ? i didn't understand

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StitchedStreamPlayer/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010092-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_9) solution, it's a full audio and video streamer.